# Como corrigir o encoding do Requests em Python?

Tags: python, json, api

Estou estudando a Requests em Python e estou tentando pegar os dados a partir do CEP: http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/

Consigo pegar, porém na hora de mostrar eles, como eu moro em São Paulo por causa do encoding eu recebo: `S\u00e3o Paulo`

Lendo o guia da requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/pt_BR/latest/user/quickstart.html#respota-json) eu sei que é possível corrigir isso usando r.encoding, porém não estou conseguindo. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
import requests

CEP = 'http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/'+ '01001001'   

r = requests.get(CEP)

r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

print r.text
```

Resultado:

> {"complemento": "lado par", "bairro": "S\u00e9", "cidade": "S\u00e3o
>   Paulo", "logradouro": "Pra\u00e7a da S\u00e9", "estado_info":
>   {"area_km2": "248.221,996", "codigo_ibge": "35", "nome": "S\u00e3o
>   Paulo"}, "cep": "01001001", "cidade_info": {"area_km2": "1521,11",
>   "codigo_ibge": "3550308"}, "estado": "SP"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse `\u` é um "escape" usado em JSON e JavaScript para caracteres não ASCII (por padrão Json usa Unicode), no caso você retornou como string, então ele mantem o uso disto para evitar perda de caracteres.

Para pegar os acentos basta fazer o "parse" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) dos dados:

```python
import json
import requests

CEP = 'http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/'+ '01001001'

r = requests.get(CEP)

jsonparsed = json.loads(r.text)

print 'logradouro: ' + jsonparsed['logradouro']
print 'complemento: ' + jsonparsed['complemento']
print 'cep: ' + jsonparsed['cep']
print 'bairro: ' + jsonparsed['bairro']

print 'cidade: ' + jsonparsed['cidade']
print 'cidade info:'
print '+--- area_km2: ' + jsonparsed['cidade_info']['area_km2']
print '+--- codigo_ibge: ' + jsonparsed['cidade_info']['codigo_ibge']

print 'estado: ' + jsonparsed['estado']
print 'estado info:'
print '+--- area_km2: ' + jsonparsed['cidade_info']['area_km2']
print '+--- codigo_ibge: ' + jsonparsed['cidade_info']['codigo_ibge']
```

Answer (score 4):

Só para complementar, a resposta do Guilherme Nascimento, não é necessário importar a biblioteca json, a própria requests já tem um método que converte retornos em json direto para dicts, como abaixo:

```
import requests
CEP = 'http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/'+ '01001001' 
r = requests.get(CEP)
print r.json()
```

Comment: Muito boa dica! +1